# Horizontal Listview inside Listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I've problem when creating a Horizontal Listview inside list view..

```
myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(thisActivity, kategoriList,
                        R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { "nama","thumbnail"}, new int[] {
                                R.id.name, R.id.thumb_kategori});

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
                listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here's the layout:
I'm using Horitontal Listview from Dev-SmartLib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Name Label -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumb_kategori"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="238dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
          android:id="@+id/listview2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
          android:divider="#FFCC00"
          android:fillViewport="false" >

      </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>

  </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But, ERROR occured when I'tried this method:
Here's the Log Cat:

```
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.lluvia.digilib.DashboardActivity$HeavyWorker.onPostExecute(DashboardActivity.java:468)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.lluvia.digilib.DashboardActivity$HeavyWorker.onPostExecute(DashboardActivity.java:1)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-26 11:09:16.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help meeee :((((((

Comment: it would help to see DashboardActivity.java lines 468 and 1 (per the error message)

Comment: Why would you want an `HorizontalListView` inside a `ListView`. Are you trying to implement some sort of `Gallery` or `GridView`?

Comment: I'll post it..
Yes, I try to make apps looks like PULSE..

Comment: The line 468 is
listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: Line 1 on DashboardActivity is package: com.lluvia.digi

Comment: Seems like `findViewById(R.id.listview2);` is returning null.

Comment: `listview2` is inside the list_item.xml which is layout of Regular Listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialized this n `getView` of your `Adapter` calss.

```
        HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
            listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

like

```
        HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.listview2);
            listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

you are initializing `HorizontalListView` in main `Activity's` layout. But it is in your `list_item.xml`